# Mapbox SDK in Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I want to show mapbox mapview in fragment but i cant do that. I looked lots of problems and solutions however i cant solve my issue. App is crashing always. BottomNavigation class is main class, MapFragment is fragment class which i want to see map. Also i attached Xml codes. Thank you!

BottomNavigation.java

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BottomNavigation extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_navigation);


        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        loadFragment(new MapFragment());

    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        if (fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

            case R.id.navigation_map:
                fragment = new MapFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_search:
                fragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_event:
                fragment = new EventsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;

        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

MapFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView;

    public MapFragment(){

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container,false);

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUrl("mapbox://styles/orucbe/cjqnneisv0gns2ro1fy83ucgl"));
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679)) // set the camera's center position
                        .zoom(12)  // set the camera's zoom level
                        .tilt(20)  // set the camera's tilt
                        .build();

                // Move the camera to that position
                mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

activity_bottom_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BottomNavigation">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting

Comment: @ManojPerumarath there is no error occuring. When app is launching, app is crashing

Comment: check the logcat there must be some errors

Comment: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: I think i need configure access token but i cant find how to configure mapbox access token in fragment @ManojPerumarath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that there is no setted **access token**. Access token should be set before inflating. That's all.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView;

    public MapFragment(){

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext().getApplicationContext(),"access_token");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container,false);

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUrl("style_url"));
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        mapView.onDestroy();

    }

}
```